# Extract number from a website using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

The following python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div = '<div class="hm"><span class="xg1">查看:</span> 15660<span class="pipe">|</span><span class="xg1">回复:</span> 435</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(div, "lxml")
hm = soup.find("div", {"class": "hm"})
print(hm)
```

The output that i want two number in this case:

```
15660
435
```

I want to try to extract the numbers from the website using beautifulsoup. But I do not know how to do it?

Comment: Remember that e.g. int('7') == 7, that is, `int()` will convert text to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `soup.find_all`, with a regex -

```
>>> list(map(str.strip, soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'\b\d+\b'))))
```

Or,

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'\b\d+\b'))]
```

```
['15660', '435']
```

---

If you need integers instead of strings, call `int` inside the list comprehension -

```
>>> [int(x.strip()) for x in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'\b\d+\b'))]
[15660, 435]
```

Comment: @wentian Thanks for accepting! You can also vote on answers if you found them helpful. Cheers.